# remove special characters from a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

I want to remove some special characters from a column in a data frame with the following script:

```
Contenido_format = []
for i in range(len(activities)):
    aux = activities['Nota'][i]
    aux = re.sub('</p>','. ',aux)
    aux = re.sub('<br>','. ',aux)
    Contenido_format.append(aux)
    
activities['Nota']=Contenido_format
```

I get the following error:
"TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"

Although it is working fine for some other columns.
I have tried to convert the column to strings with the following script:

```
activities['Nota']= activities['Nota'].map(lambda x: str(x))
```

But it is apparently merging all the data

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
activities['Nota'] = activities['Note'].str.replace('</p>|<br>', ". ")
```

Comment: How could I remove all chracters between <>?